# How to get href link from iframe of google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get href link from google map as shown in screenshot. The link is inside iframe. It gives null/error value from this below code. Google map is embed using jquery.

I tried: `

```
    var a_href = $(this).find('div .google-maps-link a').attr('href');

    var hrefs = $('#mapDiv .google-maps-link').find('a').attr('href');

    var href = $('.google-maps-link').find('a').attr('href');

    var values = $("#mapDiv .google-maps-link a").prop('href');

    var value = $("#mapDiv .gm-style .place-card .bottom-actions .google-maps-link 
    a").attr('href');
```

`

[image]

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3kEa.png)

Help me.

Update:

```
 <div class="col-md-6" id="map-location">
       <div id="dvmap"></div>
  </div>


   $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Content("~/GMap/GetGMapDataInfo")",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (result) {
            var json = JSON.parse(result.data);
            $("#dvmap").html('<iframe name="frame1" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" id="gmap_canvas"  src="' + json.MapLocation + '" width="520" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
        },
        error: function () {
        }
     });
});
```

[image: Google imbedded map]

I want to share this location (2880 Broadway)

In View large map which is in anchor tag. I need This href link.

Comment: Where is a page that contains this map?

Comment: @LeeTaylor thank you for your reply and see my updated code.

Comment: Based on my attempt this is not possible. I've used https://www.embedgooglemap.net/ to test your theory. `$("#gmap_canvas").contents()` on that page gives `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.embedgooglemap.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` Please explain what you are **actually** trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to get that href link to share others in mail. There is any other method to do that?

Comment: What specifically about that link is better than just using the link to the iframe?

Comment: I want to share pin point location in mail. As like here https://www.embedgooglemap.net/ . any other method to share link?

Comment: You want to share it from your own website, or a one off? Please update your question with the specifics of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @LeeTaylor I have posted screenshot of map. I want to share this pin location. so. I am trying to get link which is in anchor tag (View large map).

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you can not access the url of an iframe served on another domain.

Comment: There is another way to share location ? @Emil Oberg

Comment: You seem to have access to the location as `json.MapLocation` in your example. E.g. if you add the line the `$("#dvmap").append(json.MapLocation)` after `$("#dvmap")`, you should see it being output to screen and can use that to create a button or whatever you want to do with it. Or if needed, you could parse the url and extract only the location from it.